# PHP MySQL Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to write a PHP script to create 2 tables in the same database, which should be linked through a 1 (table category) to many (table page) relationship. Hence, primary key 'category_id' from the 'category' table should be the foreign key in the table 'page'.

The table 'category' creates successfully without problems:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE category(
    category_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
    UNIQUE (category)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

Then I am trying to create the second table 'page':

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE page(
    page_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (page_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (category_id)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error creating table: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the MySql manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html:

```
Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. 
The size and sign of integer types must be the same.
```

The problem is that you're specifying your foreign key as `UNSIGNED`, while your primary is not. Make sure that your foreign key matches the specifications of its parent.

Comment: I removed the UNSIGNED attribute and now it works. Table created successfully. Thanks a lot to everyone. Really appreciate the quick support.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) documentation:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. *The size and sign of integer types must be the same.*

In your `page` table, the `category_id` is `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, but in `category` it's just `SMALLINT`. They need to be exactly the same.

Comment: Nice, you and I grabbed the same quote at basically the same time (I promise I didn't see your answer first :)

Comment: @musical_coder Looks like you referenced a newer version of the documentation, so that's proof enough.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The columns used for your foreign key must have a matching specification. Here you have one category_id column signed, while the other is unsigned. Change one.

Answer (score 1):

you problem is the UNSIGNED in category_id.
try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE page(
    page_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    content LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (page_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (page.category_id) REFERENCES category (category.category_id)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```